# LLVM won't build libLLVM-3.4.so

Tags: linux, llvm

I'm trying to build llvm 3.4.2 on CentOS 7 with GCC 4.8.5. I can successfully build all of the libs, except libLLVM-3.4.so doesn't want to build - everything else gets created except that one. What's worse is I've managed it previously in the past, but can't do it again now.

I've tried both with CMake and autotools, with the same result. Is there an option I'm missing? Or some error in configuration possibly?

Comment: can you post the compile error?

Comment: There is no compile error - it just doesn't make the library, that's what's confusing.

Comment: Hold on... I'll redo the configure step and post the output, maybe there's something in there.

Comment: You mean that the compile process ends without any errors but the lib isn't there?

Comment: Yes, exactly. No errors, but no lib.

Comment: try `find . -name libLLVM-3.4.so` in your build dir. I saw a post where they say that the symlink part in the make install was broken but the file was actually created.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. No luck. I can't paste the output from CMake here as it's too long, but there's nothing that looks like a "I can't make this"-type warning.

Answer (score 6):

Found it - it was the --enable-shared flag to configure which causes the main shared library to be built. Confusingly this does something completely different from the CMake BUILD_SHARED_LIBS variable, which causes each of the individual libraries to be built as a shared library instead of static, but doesn't build the main shared library.

Comment: Well done! I was just thinking something like that. You can accept your answer but you must wait 48 hours, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB

when building from source.
The official docs say

```
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is only recommended for use by LLVM developers. If you want to build LLVM as a shared library, you should use the LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB option.
```

source: https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html